# Python script: Problem in copy object location

Tags: python, scripting

i am trying to copy z location of my object and storing it in a list for a range of keyframes but the location is not updating

```
c = 1
s =list()
while c < 251:
 bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].frame_current=c
 bpy.data.objects['Empty'].select_set(True)
 loc=bpy.data.objects["Empty"].location[2]
 s.insert(c-1,loc)
 bpy.data.objects['Empty'].select_set(False)
 c=c+1
```

i wrote list s in a file and saw that the loc does not update in the loop. Need help.

Comment: Try using `scene.frame_set(c)`  Also please use 4 character indent. 1 is frankly ridiculous.  If the empty is being moved by constraint or parenting etc try using `empty.matrix_world.translation`

Comment: Although it is not part of your question ... a suggestion regarding Python is here.  You may want to use ... for x in range(250) ... if possible. For the Python displayed, it may be a little simpler.

Comment: An extra thing, why are you using the insert method? Why not just use append() ?